# vscode g++ Link failure : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-code, g++, glfw

Basic Info:

1. system: macOS High Sierra(10.13.6)
2. editor : vs code(latest version)
3. Compiler: g++ (Xcode)
4. Target：deploy GLFW + GLAD

Question Description:
Recently, I'm learning to do some Computer Graphics related work. Everything is going smooth. However, when i create a window to test the env.Link error happened:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_gladLoadGLLoader", referenced from:
  _main in main-5c211c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

It seems I have not link some third party file. **I
have fixed exactly the same problem by add "-lglfw" args  to g++ when using functions in glfw3.h.**
But when meeting **glad related** function : gladLoadGLLoader, I don't know how to do.

Something I have done:

1. Can find the head file.

   ```
   #include glad/glad.h  
   #include GLFW/glfw3.h
   ```
2. Have put the file "glad.c" in workspace.
3. Try to Add "g++ -framework XXXXX" , But doesn't work.
4. Try to Add "g++ -lglfw3", But doesn't work.
5. Add "g++ -L or I /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/include", But doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to explicitly reference the .lib file that has `gladLoadGLLoader`, and not just specify the path to it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The `gladLoadGLLoader` is defined in `glad.c` file. Honestly, I don't know where to find .lib file that has the function. GLAD that I download only contain two .h file `glad.h` `khrplatform.h` and a src file `glad.c`,and I think I put them in the right place : headerfile in the /usr/local/include and `glad.c` in the workspace.  [glad generator address](https://glad.dav1d.de)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the g++ to compile glad.c by adding "glad.c" to args. I thought glad.c will be compiled by default. Although I am not clear what happened, the problem is resolved anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add glad.c into **Build Phases->Compile Sources**

Comment: "**Build Phases->Compile Sources**" is part of Xcode. The OP is using Visual Studio Code.